# I would like to have all the sound go through my left headphone

Tags: windows-8, audio, headphones, earbuds

I would like for all the sound to be channeled through just my left headphone. The reason for this is a little odd, but I am completely deaf in just my right ear. It is incredibly annoying to hear games or video sound through just the left, because the left right differentiation is very different in real life. I looked through the audio settings and couldn't figure it out. If possible I don't just want the left sides audio, I would like the left and the right to be played through the left.

Comment: Try converting to monaural (aka monophonic or mono).

Answer (score 0):

For default Microsoft HD Audio driver, on the playback device list, double click Headphones, this will open the `Headphones Properties` window,  select `Enhancement` tab, then enable `Headphone Virtualization`, `Studio` option seems to work best for me.

[image]

With above settings, you'll hear the original left and right channel on left headphone -- or right headphone, these two are the same now. Tested with this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTvJoYnpeRQ), but not sure about the specified game though.